# ASP Net MVC/Owin Redirect changes base Domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I have an Application, where a User is able to Access his information when he is logged in. If he trys to acces the Page when not logged in he gets redirected to the Login page. This works fine until i am trying to access the website from my external ip instead of localhost.

Normal case: The Url

```
http://localhost:50221/UserDashboard/LoggedIn
```

redirects to

```
http://localhost:50221/Account/LogIn
```

If i try to access the website via:

```
http://192.168.0.220:3000/UserDashboard/LoggedIn
```

(I am using the iis-proxy https://github.com/icflorescu/iisexpress-proxy)

I get redirected to

```
 http://localhost:50221/Account/LogIn
```

instead of

```
 http://192.168.0.220:3000/Account/LogIn
```

Is there any way to configure the Response.Redirect to use the ghiven base domain while still using relative paths ?

Comment: Why are you running this from IIS Express? Publish the application to a real IIS and you won't have this problem. IIS Express is only meant for debugging

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto because i am still in development and debugging. The Problem is, that i am using a second computer where a client is trying to access the api of this website from the local ip. (Running both client and server on the same device is sadly not possible)

Comment: Well, if anything, that is a bug in the proxy you are using. IIS Express is completely unaware of the proxy and so is the ASP.NET pipeline. You could get help from the project but as far as I've read, it's mostly dead according to the owner. You will have to either get a better proxy or run the application from IIS